# asp.net core app not working with Auth0 authentication in production

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, auth0

I am using Auth0 authentication for one of my .net core apps. In order to integrate Auth0 with my app, I followed exactly the tutorial provided here https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core.

In a dev environment, everything works fine. In other words, Auth0 authentication is called correctly and I am redirected to my app.

In the production environment, things are not working so well. The redirect URI sent to Auth0 is http://localhost/signin-auth0, whereas it should be something like http://mydomainname.com/signin-auth0.

Also in production, I am using nginx as a reverse proxy so that http://mydomainname.com:80 is redirected to http://localhost:5000, which is the address kestrel is binding to.

My questions:

- Is there something specific that I should configure in nginx so that the redirect URL is passed to Auth0 correctly?
- Where can I specify/force the redirect URL passed to Auth0?

My nginx configuration is very basic:

```
http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # List of application servers
    upstream kestrel {

        server localhost:5000;

    }


    # Configuration for the server
    server {
        # Running port
        listen *:80;
        # index index.html;
        # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
           proxy_pass http://kestrel;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host localhost;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out! My nginx configuration was messed up:

`proxy_set_header Host localhost;` should instead be `proxy_set_header Host mydomainname.com;`